# Music content for my IoT device

Tags: smart-home, streaming

I'm building my own device based on Android. I want it to play music without having to connect to Spotify or SoundCloud. Any one know of a service provider I can use for this (at minimum cost)?

I'd like to stream it from something like Spotify - but I don't want my users to have to create their own user. I'd like to create a general user and under that have profiles for my device owners.

Comment: Let's turn the question : where would you like to fetch your music ? Internal memory? DLNA server in your house?

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? Do you want to stream from something _like_ spotify, or do you want local music? Generally, music will be locked down to ensure you pay for it properly. Alternatively, you might be looking for some CC licensed music.

Comment: I'd like to stream it from something like spotify - but I don't want my users to have to create their own user. I'd like to create a general user and under that have profiles for my device owners. Makes sense?

Comment: @dafnap I've edited the extra details into the question so that it's easier for other users to find. You can [edit] when you have extra details—this will bump your post to the top of the list and get more attention. Good luck with finding your answer.

Comment: What control do you want over the stream? Free (advert supported) or are you looking to proxy the payment to your provider?

Comment: I want to pay the provider. I want transparency to my users.. I want to create a user only for me.

Comment: @dafnap You will need to edit your question to capture the details which the comments have asked about - then maybe it can be re-opened. It will probably help if you also explain why it is better for your users to follow this path rather than authenticate your device on an existing account. Unfortunately, this probably means discussing the details of your product.

Answer (score 5):

> a service provider [...] (at minimum cost)? [...] something like Spotify

Well actually there are plenty of providers "like" Spotify (depending on the definition of "likeness") and predating Spotify by decades: [Internet radio stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_radio_stations), e.g.: http://www.radiocaroline.co.uk

SHOUTcast alone has 20k+ stations. Find an extended list of providers on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_streaming_media_systems#Services) (too many to rehash it here).

---

<sub>I think the question needs to be narrowed down to get better answers.</sub>